# Why are certain random Android devices unsupported in my app's Google Play page? I've gone through the checklist

Tags: android

My application is set to API level 8+ and supported screens Small to xlarge. Most people can download it from Google Play without issue, but I have had reports that some cannot, but I cannot figure out why. Apparently, a Nexus 7 running 4.1.1 is unsupported, as is T-Mobile Comet running 2.2.

I've read the developer checklist and don't see what else could be causing their devices to have issue. Could one of the required permissions cause them not to be able to download the app? Or am I missing something else?

Here's the details from my Google Play developer page:

```
versionCode: 2
versionName: 1.0.5
Size: 10.0M
Localized to: default
Permissions: com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, android.permission.VIBRATE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.CAMERA, com.android.vending.BILLING, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, com.streamified.streamified.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
Features: android.hardware.camera, android.hardware.camera.autofocus, android.hardware.touchscreen
No main expansion file
No expansion patch file
« less
API level: 8-16+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all
```

Comment: How do these "random devices" differ from the other - supported - devices?

Comment: Nexus 7 doesn't have an ICS build

Comment: I'm unsure how the random devices differ... that's exactly why I'm asking! I included 2 known devices that are having the error though.

Comment: Apologies, the Nexus 7 is running 4.1.1. Question edited appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question states that you need the `autofocus` feature, as shown by this:

`android.hardware.camera.autofocus`

The [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/t_mobile_comet-3612.php) page for the camera doesn't list autufocus as one of the features, so that's probably why it's unsupported. Even the Nexus 7 doesn't seem to list autofocus as a feature on the [Google](http://www.google.com/nexus/#/7/specs), [Asus](http://www.asus.com/Tablet/Nexus/Nexus_7/#specifications) and [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_google_nexus_7-4850.php) pages, and I can't see it on mine either, so it should be the same reason.

If autofocus is not a complete requirement for you, use the following in your manifest to make it optional.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: This is odd; I don't have the uses-feature in my manifest. In fact, I have no reference to autofocus at all in my manifest. Maybe the uses-feature is being automatically assumed because I have the uses-permission for android.permission.CAMERA? Would this uses-feature code you pasted still make it optional and fix the problem if this is the case?

Comment: The camera permissions automatically adds the camera and autofocus features in filtering. Adding the line I provided will make autofocus optional, so it should fix the problem, for at least these two devices.

Comment: @ZaneClaes : See this documentation...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html It mentions this in the first few paragraphs and even uses the camera permission as an example.